# installing specific packages on ns2

Tags: cygwin, ns2

I want to install ns2 on my computer. After trying in some ways like:installing on Ubuntu 13.10, or installing via *cygwin* on *64 bits windows 7*, I faced with problems such as unable to find *ns.exe* in *ns-2.26* or other versions directory of *cygwin*.  Now I've installed *win XP sp3* on *VMware*, and ns2 on *cygwin* in this windows environment.  Now most of those problems(with *Ubuntu 13.10* or *cygwin* on win7) are solved but **i need to have these packages "*XFree86*"(all of them) and "*mansim*" on ns2 (v2.26). The problem here, is that i don't know where and how can i download and install them and not sure whether it's possible or not.** I've googled it but can't find useful idea.  Thanks in advance and sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved you say? Why then be interested in the year 2002 XFree86?
I.e. XFree86 hasn't been used in a new OS release since then : Redhat 9 and other OS´s from that year. (The latest OS with XFree86 was RHEL3, based on Redhat 9.)

Cygwin: If you have X (The GUI Desktop), you also have the "x-packages". (xorg-***, libX*)

---

Ubuntu: You'd usually not download software. 'apt' is used for that.

$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install g++ g++-4.4 autoconf libtool **libxmu-dev** xgraph

.... When 'libxmu-dev' is installed, you have all the required X-libraries for ns2.

---

Mannasim: There's an old patch for ns-2.29.3.

But what we mostly use today is the patch for ns-2.35. Or the complete "ns235-mannasim":

$ git clone git://github.com/paultsr/ns-allinone-2.35.git

Mannasim INFO:

- http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/tags/mannasim/
- https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/ns-users/mannasim|sort:date